# convert a SOAP C# client to PHP

Tags: c#, php, soap

Good day all.
I'm converting a C# Soap client in PHP, with many troubles.
I don't know C# but the syntax is quite legible, so I don't have many problems, until now.

these are the lines I can't understand:

```
My_Arx_Search.Field_String campo = ((My_Arx_Search.Field_String)aggSearch);
campo.Operatore = My_Arx_Search.Dm_Base_Search_Operatore_String.Uguale;
campo.Valore = "DFLMHLD15GGFD...";
```

What I actually know is:
`My_Arx_Search` is (I suppose) an instance of the xml of the wsdl (there is a file called the same, which is exactly that).
how I can manage these 2 lines in php? anyone can help me in that?
thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using Visual Studio? if you're you can access the method and see the documentation (if it is a framework method) or his actual implementation

Comment: no, I only got some files from a previous developer (who i cannot contact at this moment)...

Comment: open the project in Visual Studio, you can download a version for free, it will make you're life so much easier.

Comment: eheh, thanks, i'll surely try that! thanks very much!

Comment: I don't know what would you need the C# code for , if you have your wsdl create your proxy class in php and call it as you should , if you're good in PHP it would be a piece of cake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
My_Arx_Search.Field_String campo = ((My_Arx_Search.Field_String)aggSearch);
```

This creates a variable "campo" of type "My_Arx_Search.Field_String", and as value, converts the variable "aggSearch" to this type.

```
campo.Operatore = My_Arx_Search.Dm_Base_Search_Operatore_String.Uguale;
```

This assigns the value on the right to the "Operatore" field of the "campo" variable. I assume it's either a static field, or an enum.

```
campo.Valore = "DFLMHLD15GGFD...";
```

This assignes the value "DFL..." to the "Valore" field of the "campo" variable.

Without the definition of the "My_Arx_Search.Field_String" class I can't help you more.